# How to add Rows with missed values using Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

I have to add new row with missed Area Values.

Below is input excel.

```
Name  Depth Module  Total Area      Category    Sub category
       0    Module0    50           Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module11   1            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module12   9            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module21   3            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module22   5            Category_1  Category_2

       1    Module13   5            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module21   2            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module22   1            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module23   1            Category_1  Category_2

       1    Module14   2            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module15   3            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module16   4            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module17   7            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module18   6            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module19   2            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module120  5            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module121  3            Category_1  Category_2
```

Explanation of input excel:
In the Above Excel sheet, Depth is nothing but Layer. 
Input contains, Depth 0 is divided into number of Depth 1's Means Sum of Depth 1 should be equal to depth 0. Depth 1 (1+9+5+2+3+4+7+6+2+5+3 = 47) But Depth 0 is 50, so, missed Total_Area is 3(50-47).
I have to add 3 value as Depth 1 with categories.

similarly, Depth 1 is divided into Depth 2, So Sum of Depth 2 is equal to Depth 1. Let's take row number 3. Module12(9) is divided into No. of Depth 2's (3+5=8), here missed Total_Area is 1(9-8).

So, I have added extra row called MISC, which has missed Total Area.
I need to add MISC row using python. preferable : Pandas

I have tried below script. But it supports only one row, i need to add entire excel sheet with missed Total_Area column.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

ip = "test.xlsx"
op = "test1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(ip, 'Sheet1') 

def Insert_row(row_number, df, row_value): 
    start_upper = 0 
    end_upper = row_number 
    start_lower = row_number 
    end_lower = df.shape[0] 
    upper_half = [*range(start_upper, end_upper, 1)] 
    lower_half = [*range(start_lower, end_lower, 1)] 
    lower_half = [x.__add__(1) for x in lower_half] 
    index_ = upper_half + lower_half 
    df.index = index_ 
    df.loc[row_number] = row_value 
    df = df.sort_index() 
    return df  

row_number = 7 
row_value = ['MISC',2 , 'MISC',1 ,'Category_1' ,'Category_2'] 

if row_number > df.index.max()+1: 
    print("Invalid row_number") 
else: 
    df = Insert_row(row_number, df, row_value) 
    df.to_excel(op, index=False)
```

Expected Output:

```
Name  Depth Module  Total Area      Category    Sub category
       0    Module0    50           Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module11   1            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module12   9            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module21   3            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module22   5            Category_1  Category_2
**MISC   2    MISC       1          Category_1  Category_2**
       1    Module13   5            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module21   2            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module22   1            Category_1  Category_2
       2    Module23   1            Category_1  Category_2
**MISC   2    MISC     1            Category_1  Category_2**
       1    Module14   2            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module15   3            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module16   4            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module17   7            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module18   6            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module19   2            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module120  5            Category_1  Category_2
       1    Module121  3            Category_1  Category_2
**MISC   1  MISC       3            Category_1  Category_2**
```

Comment: I think changing `df.loc[row_number] = row_value` to `df.iloc[ ... ] = ... ` would solve the problem. As, **.loc[]** is label based,  whereas **.iloc[]** is index or integer based.

Comment: Thanks @Subrata but My excel file has more than 5,000 lines. So, i am thinking, row_number also should take from script. my script should be insert row, populate the required Depth and Total_Area Values. 
If you have any logics, could yo please give me.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the original data? I'm not quite sure about how you would fill the data automatically as I see lines 4 and 8 have same Depth, Module, Category and Sub category. I can only think of splitting the file by the empty lines.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo, I have concentrated on only Total_Area and Depth values. Line number 4 (Total Depth Split up is 9 but here out of 9 I have categorized 3 only ) is split up of Line number 3.  where as Line number 8 (Total Depth split up is 5. out of 5 here categorized 2) Is split up of Line number 7.

I have Splitted Depth 0 to Depth 1 and 
Depth 1 to Depth 2.
Sum of all Depth 1's should be equal to Depth 0.
I have categorized some Depth 1's to Depth 2.
So, Sum of Depth 2 should be the value of Depth 1(previous row.)

Comment: How many depths you have? Is it only till 2?

Comment: No, In my Data frame it will be till Depth 15. But as a example i have shown till 2.